# C# mvc5 add Textbox by Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

is it possible to add a texbox by controller to a View?

I have a dynamic number of textboxes and need a way to add this by the Controller to the View. Is this Possible?

Comment: You could do this by using a collection in your view model and then foreach over that collection in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      Do Something like this. Just a quick written code. Might be syntax errors.

      DynamicTextBoxCreation.cs    
      public class DynamicTextBoxCreation
        {
            public List<string> textBoxList;

            public ActionResult DynamicTextBox()
            {
               /* Fill your dynamic list here from DB or from any other logic */
               return textBoxList;
            }
        }

        DynamicTextBox.cshtml            
        @model DynamicTextBoxCreation;
        @code{
          var i = 1;
        }

        foreach(var tbItem in textBoxList)
        {
            @Html.TextBox(' + tbItem + i + ', "", new {@class = "css-class", @onclick = "alert('demo');"});
            i += 1;
        }
```